# Unable to login after sysRq+REISUB

Tags: sysrq

I was watching a Youtube video and playing around with a C++ script, when the OS got completely frozen.

I did <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>REISUB</kbd>, so it rebooted.

But I am now able to login as guest only.

My user login (from which I was originally working) just idle for 10/15sec then blacks out, and I am at the login screen again.

Any hints?

Comment: The key may be "playing around with a c++ script" - can you remember what you did there?

Comment: Just modifying a simple script in vim and compiling it for test runs... basic stuff like variables, loops and IO examples.

Comment: There are so many possible causes... see https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop for plenty of solutions.

Comment: So I performed most actions that were mentioned in the post which @takkat pointed. Though, it didn't solve the problem.  
I reinstalled lightdm, but nothing.  
I installed lxde and I could access to my account, but it was still bad since I could only see the empty background, no unity bar or else.  
So reading this https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears?noredirect=1&lq=1, I reinstalled unity-desktop (perhaps not needed), and the command ``$ mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old`` sorted it out.  
Thank you